# react app - build application is not working on server but development code does

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, nginx, server, nginx-config

I'm totally new in to frameworks.

I can easily put my dev files like: package.json,package-lock.json, src,public,node_modules.
And run them with typing sudo npm start.

It is by portfolio website in progress so for now I don't have any backend programs only HTML with some client functions.

From what I understand I should only put my build files that have been created from "npm run build".

When I remove dev files and put build files I got "502 bad gateway nginx" error on page.

I'm not sure if there is a command I should write to start it or server should somehow start it itself?

I have server on hostinger. running ubuntu and nginx
node is up to date on the server.

Also I'm using cPannel as I coudln't properly install everything and configure to make it work so i made a format and install cpanel instead.

so looks like from the cPannel it should read the index file from the build.
[image: root directory ss]